# How to store and retrieve images from database in Android app programming

Tags: java, android, database, android-fragments, android-activity

I am new to Android app programming. I created one activity which contains a bottom navigation bar (with 3 buttons) and  fragments.
If you click on the first button, the user profile will appear. Now I would like the user to chose an image from his device. This image should be saved in a database and this is exactely the point I got stucked. Which database is used in app programming and what api I will need to store and retrieve images from that database so that I can put it into an ImageView.
I hope somebody can be of further help.
Thanks!

Comment: Saving images in DB is not a good practice, if you want to do it anyway use GreenDao ORM to save image as byte array in SQLITE.

Comment: Thanks for your reply. What is good practice?

Comment: as Jason shared below, store it on your device storage or you can use Picasso to process image directly from server.

Answer (score 0):

If this is just for fun, store it locally on the device. If this is for enterprise, send the image data over TCP, or some reliable protocol, to a remote server to be stored in a database. You can use relational, or non relational.

Here is how to do it without a server
[How to display the image from database in android imageview](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27168303/how-to-display-the-image-from-database-in-android-imageview/27168532)

Answer (score 0):

I assume you want to store the image on cloud and then retrieve it based on user, for this best option is to go for firebase, you can use firebase realtime database to store data and firebase storage to store files such as PDF or images.
For example you can store image in firebase storage and store it's URL in firebase realtime database along with user details.

Here is documentation for firebase :- https://firebase.google.com/docs/android/setup
How to setup app with firebase and all the APIs you can use to read/write to firebase.